# I can't write to network folder (20.04)

Tags: 20.04, permissions, mount, samba, fstab

I have a problem with write resources to mapped network folder on the computer. I have  computers (10 devices) with Ubuntu 18.04 (all are OK) and computers (4 devices) with Ubuntu 20.04 (problem). Resources are on a server running Linux OpenSUSE 10.2 and and shared via Samba.

`/etc/fstab` on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
//IP/nzoz /home/user/folder cifs vers=1.0,username=xxx,password=xxx,gid=1001,uid=1001,rw,user,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

The `/etc/fstab` file on Ubuntu 20.04 is same as on 18.04 (I remember about `uid` and `gid`).

In 20.04 I have access and I can read resources but I can't write.

So in my server change permission main directory `chmod 777`. The problem is the same except that I can only create new directories but the new directory has padlock and in the new directory i can't write.

[image]

Thank you in advance for your response.

Comment: Are you certain the CIFS version should be `1.0` rather than auto-negotiated? Alternatively, I have found that Ubuntu often needs `nounix` to be added after the `file_mode` and `dir_mode` options when Samba is being hosted on non-Debian-based OSes 

Comment: Tanks done!!!!, I gave 'nounix' after 'file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,nounix 0 0' and restart computer. All is good i can write documents. Thank you very much.